# Do you know alternatives to Buildix?

Tags: java, version-control, maven-2, continuous-integration, live-cd

[Buildix](http://buildix.thoughtworks.com/) is a complete development server (by ThoughtWorks) for Continuous Integration

I'm looking for a pre-configured server with Maven, Subversion, Sonar, Nexus...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just happened to read about [SecureCI](http://www.coveros.com/research/research_stack.php) yesterday on [The Build Doctor blog](http://www.build-doctor.com/2009/09/05/covero). Seems like just what you're asking for.

Comment: Quite amazing, i've got an full-configured server in 5 minuntes

Answer (score 1):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is one of the best CI tools around, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, correct me if i'm wrong but AFAIK TeamCity is a Build Management app (as Hudson or CruiseControl).

Buildix is more a 'stack' including Maven, Subversion ...

Comment: @Benoit you are right, TeamCity is a continuous integration and build management system that integrates with build tools such as Ant, Maven2, MSBuild, NAnt, Rake, Command Line runner. It is not a build tool itself